# Best approach to wait for an object to show up in S3 before retrieving it

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am trying to figure out the best way to wait/get an object from a bucket in AWS S3 without having to constantly poll for it until I retrieve it. This object is being sent from a different service.

The approach I was going with was running Thread.sleep() and sleeping for the approximate time it takes for the object to reach the bucket before trying to retrieve it.

Another was using a for loop to constantly pull the object until I receive it.

These two approaches work but it can be time consuming/expensive

Any tips/suggestions would be great. Thank you!

Comment: Rather than having to poll for it, Amazon S3 can trigger an S3 Event when an object is created. This Event can push a message to an Amazon SNS topics, an Amazon SQS queue or trigger an AWS Lambda function. This way, your code can 'respond' to the creation event rather than having to continually check if the object exists. What were you wanting to do once the object exists -- can you do that activity in a Lambda function?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein thanks for responding! I have a maven junit test running in a ci/cd pipeline that triggers this object creation in s3. What I would like to do is get the object, parse the contents on the object and run assertions within my test. I haven’t worked much with aws lambda but it may not work for my use case?

Comment: Probably not. The Lambda function will run independently. It's great if you want to process a file after upload (eg convert to PDF or use OCR) but that type of flow probably won't work well with your test pipeline requirements.

Comment: You haven't provided any indication whether or not your process even has a way to be notified. If it includes some way to be notified then a Lambda function can likely notify it. If it doesn't have a way, then I don't see any option for you but to poll.

Comment: If your application creates the file and uploads it to S3, why not create a test adapter to store it locally, or mock the S3 upload part? If your application tells some other system to upload a file to S3 so you can test it, then why not just have a local copy of what the file should look like... If you want to test the generation of the file, that should happen on the system generating it. If you want to test the processing of the file, you should create the file locally and skip S3 upload/download. You can also use LocalStack + TestContainers to simulate S3 locally in your pipeline.